# Let $(G,*)$ be a finite group and $a \in G$. Show that $\circ(a) \le |G|$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G,*)$ be a finite group and
$a \in G$. Show that $\circ(a) \le |G|$.
($\circ(a)$ denote the order of $a$.)

This is the given hint:
Suppose that $|G|=n$. Note that
$\{e_G,a,a^2,\ldots,a^n\} \subseteq G$ and $G$ has $n$ elements.

How to approach $\circ(a) \le |G|$?
Does the given hint means that: "there exists integers $p$ and $q$ with $p>q$ such that $a^p=a^q$.
Then, $a^{p-q} = e_G$. Write $m=p-q$ and hence $a^m = e_G$ for some integer $m$, with $0\le m \le n-1$." ?

Comment: What is ○? Order of the element?

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes, the order of an element.

Comment: the given "hint" is almost a complete answer, lol.

Comment: @Masacroso But, how to imply $\circ(a) \le |G|$ ?

Comment: @user795084 because $p,q\leqslant n+1$, that is, observe that the list $g,g^2,g^3,\ldots ,g^{n+1}$ have at most $n$ distinct elements

Comment: Yes, if you proceed by contradiction, ie, suppose that $o(a)\gt n$, then the hint implies there exist integers $0\le q\lt p\le n$ such that $a^{p-q}=e_G$ but note that $p-q\lt n$, which contradicts $o(a)\gt n$; the crux is that $\{a^0,a^1,\ldots,a^n\}\subseteq G$ has two elements same by PHP (pigeonhole principle) since it has $n+1$ elements which is greater than the cardinality of $G$ itself.

Comment: It is a normal English word, not a particular mathematical term: look up "crux definition" on Google.

Comment: No, I'm considering $0\le q$ because my argument uses the span of $a$ starting from $a^0=e_G$; since $q\lt p$, we have that $p-q$ is a positive integer and the argument applies. You can also consider $0\lt q\lt p\leq n\color{red}{+1}$ if your argument uses the list $a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n+1}$ and the previous argument applies.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Why can $o(a) \gt n$ implies exists integers such that?

Answer (score 4):

If all the elements of the set $\{e_G,a,a^2,\ldots, a^n\}$ were distinct, it would contain $n+1$ elements. As $G$ has only $n$ elements, there must be a repeat. Therefore, the argument you propose must follow.

Comment: Is ".... argument you propose...." refers to "Does the given .... ?" ?

Comment: Yes. $\hspace{1in}

Comment: If $a^m = e_G$ for some integer $0\le m \le n-1$, then it follows that the order of $a$ is always less than or equal to $|G|$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach?

Suppose that $|G| = n$. Let $a \in G$
and $\circ(a) = k$. Let $H = \langle a \rangle$. Then, $|H| = |\langle a \rangle| = \circ(a) = k$. Hence, by Langrange's Theorem, $k$ divides $n$ and
thus $k \le n$ as desired.

Comment: Can I write $\langle a \rangle$ by $\{e_G,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$?

Comment: If $\circ(a)=k$ then $\langle a\rangle =\{e_G,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{k-1}\}$. Note that Lagrange's Theorem is overkill if you just want $k\leq n$ (versus $k|n$ which is stronger). You have $|H|=k$, $|G|=n$, and $H\subseteq G$. So $k=|H|\leq |G|=n$.

Comment: @halrankard2 What proof that not using Lagrange? I mean, the elementary proof.

Comment: @halrankard2 Is the above approach (on question) implies order of $a$ is less than or equal to order of $G$?

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you just want to prove $k\leq n$, then you don't need Lagrange's Theorem. You have the set $H$ (which has size $k$) as a subset of the set $G$ (which has size $n$). So clearly $k\leq n$. In other words, in your proof replace "Hence, by Lagrange's Theorem, $k$ divides $n$" with "$H$ is a subset of $G$". You obtain a perfectly good proof of $k\leq n$ that does not mention Lagrange's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

How about the theorem of Lagrange?  For one number to divide another it must not be greater than it.

Comment: How to prove without Lagrange? I mean, the elementary proof and only using the definition of order of an element in group.

Comment: Since two of the first $n+1$ powers of $a$ have to be equal, we get that $a^k=a^l\implies a^{k-l}=e\implies |a|\mid(k-l)\implies|a|\le n$.